# Twitter Typeahead and bootstrap-tagsinput styling not correct in IE and Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### Summary

I have recently been working on a message system for my website which consists of Twitter Typeahead plugin and bootstrap-tagsinput plugin. But I am having styling problems with my css when I load my page in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome whereas it works fine in firefox (probably because I used it for development and initial style editing). I was wondering how to fix this as I am not very experienced in css which is why Iv'e tried to make this question as easy on the eyes as possible.

Read Below for my issues.

---

### Working In Firefox (Developed In)

Below are images of my input box working correctly in firefox:
[image]

[image]

---

### Internet Explorer Styling Problems (EDIT: FIXED!)

1. Input box is not aligned with glyphicon until I add a tag.
   [image]
2. Input text is not alligned with the tags to the left.
   [image]
3. Placeholder font colour and style does not correspond with the rest of the form.
   [image]

---

### Google Chrome Styling Problem (EDIT: FIXED)

Typeahead dropdown it not aligned properly. 
(only occurs on the first tag otherwise is works fine).
[image]

---

### Code

My HTML:

```
<span id="remote" class="input-group" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="font-size: 15px;"></span></span>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="msgUser" id="msgUser" class="form-control tagsInput" placeholder="Users Seperated by ,"/>
</span>
```

Typeahead CSS:

```
.accordion {
    margin-bottom:-3px;
}

.accordion-group { 
    border: none;
}

.twitter-typeahead .tt-query,
.twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.twitter-typeahead .tt-hint
{
    display: none;
}

.tt-dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.tt-suggestion > p {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tt-suggestion > p:hover,
.tt-suggestion > p:focus,
.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor p {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #428bca;
}
```

Bootstrap Tagsinput CSS:

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput { width: 100%; }

.label-info {
  background-color: #ededed !important;
}
.label-info[href]:hover,
.label-info[href]:focus {
  background-color: #ededed !important;
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 22px;
  cursor: text;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput input {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto !important;
  max-width: inherit;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput input:focus {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  margin-right: 2px;
  color: #555555;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag:hover {
  border-color: #b9b9b9;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"] {
  border: none;
  margin-left: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:after {
  content: "x";
  padding: 0px 2px;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:hover:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

Comment: Can include `js` ?, create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Agreed. A fiddle would be good. I can't recreate your problem.

Comment: fixed, was my fault for not posting the js files.

Answer (score 2):

My fault that no one else could resolve this question, I shouldv'e included the javascript files too, I fixed it by editing these lines in twitter typahead js file:

```
var css = function() {
    "use strict";
    var css = {
        wrapper: {
            // HACK: make dropdown display in chrome properly
            //position: "relative",
            //display: "inline-block"
            position: "relative",
            verticalAlign: "top"
```

The wrapper wasn't sitting right in the first input and this seemed to fix it.